# Write files to disk with python 3.x

Tags: python, file, upload, python-3.x, bottle

Using BottlePy, I use the following code to upload a file and write it to disk :

```
upload = request.files.get('upload')
raw = upload.file.read()
filename = upload.filename
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(raw)
return "You uploaded %s (%d bytes)." % (filename, len(raw))
```

It returns the proper amount of bytes every single time.

The upload works fine for file like `.txt`, `.php`, `.css` ...

But it results in a corrupted file for other files like `.jpg`, `.png`, `.pdf`, `.xls` ...

I tried to change the `open()` function

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
```

It returns the following error:

> TypeError('must be bytes or buffer, not str',)

I guess its an issue related to binary files ?

Is there something to install on top of Python to run upload for any file type ?

---

Update

Just to be sure, as pointed out by @thkang I tried to code this using the dev version of bottlepy and the built-in method .save()

```
upload = request.files.get('upload')
upload.save(upload.filename)
```

It returns the exact same Exception error

```
TypeError('must be bytes or buffer, not str',)
```

---

Update 2

Here the final code which "works" (and dont pop the error `TypeError('must be bytes or buffer, not str',)`

```
upload = request.files.get('upload')
raw = upload.file.read().encode()
filename = upload.filename
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(raw)
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same : every `.txt` file works fine, but other files like `.jpg`, `.pdf` ... are corrupted

I've also noticed that those file (the corrupted one) have a larger size than the orginal (before upload)

This binary thing must be the issue with Python 3x

Note :

- I use python 3.1.3
- I use BottlePy 0.11.6 ([raw bottle.py file](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py), no 2to3 on it or anything)

Comment: doesn't bottle have `.save()` method on file objects?

Comment: Yes it is in the dev docs, i tried it but gets me an error `AttributeError('save',)` (I got version 0.11.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3x all strings are now unicode, so you need to convert the `read()` function used in this file upload code.

The `read()` function returns a unicode string aswell, which you can convert into proper bytes via `encode()` function

Use the code contained in my first question, and replace the line

```
raw = upload.file.read()
```

with

```
raw = upload.file.read().encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

That's all ;)

Further reading : http://python3porting.com/problems.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
upload = request.files.get('upload')

with open(upload.file, "rb") as f1:
    raw = f1.read()
    filename = upload.filename
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(raw)

    return "You uploaded %s (%d bytes)." % (filename, len(raw))
```

**Update**

Try `value`:

```
# Get a cgi.FieldStorage object
upload = request.files.get('upload')

# Get the data
raw = upload.value;

# Write to file
filename = upload.filename
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(raw)

return "You uploaded %s (%d bytes)." % (filename, len(raw))
```

**Update 2**

See [this thread](http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_file_upload), it seems to do same as what you are trying...

```
# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:

   # strip leading path from file name to avoid directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open('files/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'
```

Comment: I tried, it returns an error for the 1st open() line `TypeError("invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name=6 encoding='utf-8'>",)` (this error is send for every type of file)

Comment: @Koffee Share your declarations for `request`.

Comment: Eeer i tried everything and keep getting the same error `TypeError('must be bytes or buffer, not str',)` 
I changed the code with function `encode()` to convert str to bytes, but the result is the same. I strongly suspect an issue with python 3x and bytes (see update)

Comment: I just tried whith the full code fom the link you provided in Update 2, it too returns the error `TypeError('must be bytes or buffer, not str',)`